# JSF State saving and custom components with dynamically added children

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, custom-component

I am developing a JSF custom component. This component has the purpose of encapsulating another component (namely a PrimeFaces table) and adding customized behaviour to it. For example, one of the features that it supports is creating PrimeFaces columns dynamically from the underlying data or from certain attributes. Furthermore, it supports declaring additional PrimeFaces columns in XHTML, which should be added to the encapsulated PrimeFaces table as well.

Consider this example:

```
<my:table id="table" fields="title,label,value,additional">
    <primefaces:column id="additional">
        some content
    </primefaces:column>
</my:table>
```

My custom component dynamically creates the PrimeFaces columns from the `fields` attribute during rendering. It then moves all its `column` children to the PrimeFaces table, so after rendering the component tree looks like follows:

```
my:table id="table"
|---primefaces:table id="table_table"
    |---primefaces:column id="title"
    |---primefaces:column id="label"
    |---primefaces:column id="value"
    |---primefaces:column id="additional"
```

During first rendering, this works fine. However, when I then perform an AJAX update of my component, I get the following exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot remove the same component twice: table:additional
    at com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$DynamicAddRemoveListener.handleAddRemoveWithAutoPrune(StateContext.java:761)
    at com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$DynamicAddRemoveListener.handleRemove(StateContext.java:629)
    at com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$AddRemoveListener.processEvent(StateContext.java:342)
    at com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$DynamicAddRemoveListener.processEvent(StateContext.java:565)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListenersAccountingForAdds(ApplicationImpl.java:2218)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeViewListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2036)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.disconnectFromView(UIComponentBase.java:2275)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPreRemoveProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1939)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:437)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.remove(UIComponentBase.java:2757)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.adjustIndexOfDynamicChildren(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:225)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at de.gebit.trend.servlet.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, only the `column` that was moved from my table to the PrimeFaces table is creating this error. The other columns do not get recreated, because during rendering, I use an instance variable stored in the `StateHelper` to indicate that columns are already created.

I somehow understand where this exception is coming from and that it has something to do with JSF saving the complete component tree, and when JSF restores the view, the saved state is inconsistent with the XHTML. What I don't know is, how to solve this problem.

Could someone please explain to me how this state saving mechanism exactly works, especially in conjunction with dynamically added children and how to avoid this exception?

## UPDATE (10.02.2017)

I've created a small sample project without additional frameworks that were in use before. It can be found on my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/jessepeng/jsf-dynamic-children-test). One main framework that was in use before was fiddeling with the `AddRemoveListeners` installed in the `StateContext` for replaying dynamic actions. To avoid this having an impact on my issue and to create a reproducible environment, I removed them.

The behavior I witness now is slightly different (there are no exceptions anymore) and depends on whether **partial state saving** is enabled/disabled and the method I use to move the `primefaces:column`:

The first rendering of the table in all cases works fine. I then perform a postback request by submitting a paging request. The behavior then is erronous in some cases.

### Partial state saving enabled

With partial state saving enabled, paging does not work. I do not get an exception, but a lot of warnings similar to this:

```
Feb 10, 2017 4:33:11 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy saveDynamicActions
WARNUNG: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:table:table_table:additional' because the UIComponent cannot be found
```

This warning appears for every component that was moved dynamically created in or moved to the `primefaces:table` or was a child component of one of those.

### Partial state saving disabled

With partial state saving disabled, paging does work but shows different behavior depending on when the one custom `primefaces:column` is moved.

#### Moving of `column` during render response phase

When the `primefaces:column` is moved during render response phase, e.g. in `encodeXxx`, everything works fine. All the columns are in the correct order and with correct values and paging works perfectly fine.

#### Moving of `column` using a `PostAddToViewEvent`

When using this approach, as per **@BalusC** suggestion, the moved `primefaces:column` disappears on paging. The `PostAddToViewEvent` is called several times and the `column` is moved while handling this event, however on rendering, it has disappeared and only the three previously created `column`s are still there.

At this point, I am more than confused. Is this a bug in Mojarra or in Primefaces or am I doing something wrong? Is this kind of behavior even possible with JSF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is: it is the other frameworks fault that is in use. This framework overwrites the state saving mechanism of JSF and replaces it with a custom mechanism. The implementation, however, was faulty and did not take care of the `DynamicAddRemoveListener`s responsible for saving the actions of dynamic componants correctly. They fixed the bug, now it works fine.

However, there were several things that were necessary to fix my component that I want to point out:

*First*, **@BalusC** pointed me to the correct way of moving child components in a custom JSF component: it should be done using a `PostAddToView` event listener.

> ```
> @ListenerFor(systemEventClass=PostAddToViewEvent.class)
> public class YourComponent extends SomeUIComponent {
>
>      @Override
>      public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
>           if (event instanceof PostAddToViewEvent) {
>               targetParent.getChildren().add(componentToMove);
>           }
>      }
> }
> ```

This approach has the drawback, however, that the components attributes won't be set at this point. So if you need those, components can only be created/moved during render response phase.

*Second*, child components of a custom JSF component should not be saved in the `StateHelper`. They should be recreated on every request so that JSF finds these components when replaying the dynamic actions.

*Third*, the ID of dynamically created child components (if set) should always be set when the component is created itself. My custom component set the ID of its children components only during render response phase, so when JSF tried to replay the dynamic actions, it could not find the respective components. This was the solution to the problem mentioned above in the section **Partial state saving enabled**.

So with all these adaptions and the fix for the other framework, now finally my component works as desired.

Answer (score 11):

JSF state management remembers dynamic manipulations to the component tree so that it can ensure that it's after the restore view of a postback **exactly the same** as it was during render response of the previous request which generated the post form.

The exception which you got,

> javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot remove the same component twice: table:additional

basically tells that you've added the very same component twice to the same parent.

In other words, you obtained the desired component from the component tree and then added it to the desired parent. However, as per the given exception, it was at that moment **already** attached to the desired parent! Effectively, you performed a no-op. But JSF remembers every single dynamic component add/remove through postbacks on the same view, even though it's effectively a no-op. That part may in turn be a bug in JSF implementation itself, but you should in first place not be moving around components when they are aready in the desired place.

A quick fix would be to check the component's parent by `UIComponent#getParent()` if it isn't already the desired one and if so then skip the `getChildren().add()` call.

```
if (!componentToMove.getParent().equals(targetParent)) {
    targetParent.getChildren().add(componentToMove);
}
```

A hack would be to set [`UIComponent#setInView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setInView-boolean-) to `false` so that JSF doesn't remember the dynamic action.

```
componentToMove.setInView(false);
targetParent.getChildren().add(componentToMove);
componentToMove.setInView(true);

// NOTE: with MyFaces, call setInView() on componentToMove.getParent() instead.
```

Be however cautious when using this method, see also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setInView-boolean-).

However, the most natural way to perform component tree manipulations is a `postAddtoViewEvent` listener instead of during `encodeXxx()` method.

```
@ListenerFor(systemEventClass=PostAddToViewEvent.class)
public class YourComponent extends SomeUIComponent {

@Override
public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof PostAddToViewEvent) {
        targetParent.getChildren().add(componentToMove);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used the `PostAddToViewEvent` approach and it works fine when the component is rendered for the first time. However, when a following postback request is fired, the event does not get fired (as per the specification). This happens for example when paging in the primefaces table is used. For some reason, the `<primefaces:column id="additional">` component then gets put back to the old position directly below `<my:table id="table">`. This is why I mentioned the state saving mechanism, because I have the feeling that that is involed in this.

Comment: Okay, I overlooked that the `PostAddToViewEvent` is fired twice, once by the custom component itself and once by `UIViewRoot`. So when fixing this, the component can be moved on each request. Now, it works as expected for the initial rendering and for up to 2 paging requests (which are AJAX requests fired by the PrimeFaces table). However, on submitting the third paging request, I get the same exception I got in the first place.

Comment: Which Mojarra version? What's the behavior when you set context param `javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE` to `true`?

Comment: It's Mojarra version 2.2.14. And with `javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE` set to `true` the same thing happens. I've noticed that the number of `com.sun.faces.context.StateContext.DynamicAddRemoveListener` listeners for `javax.faces.event.PreRemoveFromViewEvent` varies for each paging request: for the first paging request, there are two seperate listeners. For the second paging request, there is only one listener, but a different one from the first two. And for the third (failing) paging request, there are two again, where the first one is the same as the second (hence the exception).

Comment: When setting `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` to false, everything works as expected and no exception occurs.

Comment: Interesting. This indicates a bug in partial state saving. You'd however rather not turn off it as it can have a performance impact. Thanks for feedback. I updated the answer with snippets how to correctly use one or other approach. Have you already tried the proposed quick fix or hack?

Comment: I've seen other comparable Mojarra issues in my code that were solved by setting partial state saving to false. Will see if I can dig them up

Comment: @Kukeltje A lot wrt dynamic actions has been fixed in progress to 2.2.14, but new issues are more than welcome.

Comment: @BalusC The quick fix does not work in my case, because the parent at that point in time is always `my:table`. The hack also does not work, I then get the exception on the first paging request, but not for the `primefaces:column` element, but rather for an element nested inside this column. We do however use another framework which could also be the reason for this exception, because it uses an own `ViewHandler` which might be buggy. I will investigate further.

Comment: To be clear, the quick fix and hack need to be performed during render response phase (e.g. `preRenderViewEvent` or `encodeXxx()`). They don't have the desired effect during `postAddToViewEvent`.

Comment: @BalusC Well if I move the column during render response phase, then I'm back at where I started: during initial rendering and after the view is built, the column is moved to the right position, but during a following paging request I get the exception, because for some reason it ends up as a direct child of `my:table` again.

Comment: I updated my question with new findings I found. I get more confused the deeper I dig into this.

Comment: Is the `<p:dataTable>` itself dynamically created or enclosed in `<my:table>` ?

Comment: It's rendered dynamically and created during component creation.

Comment: Hm, so `<my:table>` is also an `UIComponent` and not a tagfile?

Comment: Yes, it's a JSF custom component that actually extends from `UIPanel`. During first creation it creates a PrimeFaces `DataTable` during component creation using a `ComponentHandler` and adds it as a child. It also puts this `DataTable` in the `StateHelper` so that it doesn't get recreated on every request. Could this be a problem?

Comment: That could very well be the cause of your problem, yes. `UIComponent` instances do not belong in JSF state. Either make it a tagfile with `<p:dataTable><ui:insert/></p:dataTable>` or let it extend from `DataTable` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't `setTransient(true)` disable the state helper thing?