# How to add sub components to JSF custom component to obtain valid client IDs?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, custom-component, mojarra

I have created a custom component and custom renderer which should use additional sub components like so:

```
doEncodeBegin(...){
  final HtmlOutcomeTargetLink commandLink = (HtmlOutcomeTargetLink) context.getApplication().createComponent(HtmlOutcomeTargetLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
  cmdLink.setId("myLink");
  cmdLink.setParent(component);
  cmdLink.encodeAll(context);
}
```

If the custom component has ID "myComp" the sub component should get the client ID "myComp:myLink".

However, sometimes (e.g. in validation phase) I get the following error message: "Cannot add the same component twice".

==> What is the actual problem here?

Tried solutions - as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41857584/195216) by BalusC:

1. Using setTransient(true) to the component didn't help.
2. Using setInView(false) helped but I think that is not a valid solution either?!