# PrimeFaces TreeTable Issue on Mojarra

Tags: primefaces, mojarra, jsf-2.3

I have a programmatic Dynamic TreeTable that is created and added to a form panel. This issue is only reproducible in Mojarra.

The code works only with

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

or

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
        <param-value>/treetableprogram.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable - primefaces 6.2 , jsf 2.3.3
https://github.com/ravihariharan/primefaces-test-treetable.git

*treetableprogram.xhtml, BasicView1.java*

Based on PrimeFaces showcase example : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    root = service.createDocuments();

    TreeTable table = new TreeTable();
    table.setId("treeTableId");
    table.setVar("document");
    table.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{ttBasicView1.root}", TreeNode.class));

    Column column = new Column();
    column.setId("col1");
    OutputLabel label = new OutputLabel();
    label.setId("ol1");
    label.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{document.name}", String.class));

    column.getChildren().add(label);

    table.getChildren().add(column);

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
    viewRoot.findComponent("form:mainPanel").getChildren().add(table);
}
```

The issue

1. The TreeTable cannot be expanded or collapsed after the initial load.
2. Code works only with javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING false in Mojarra which is not the ideal case.
3. Warning message on click on expanded 
   Jun 11, 2018 3:13:29 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy saveDynamicActions
   WARNING: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:treeTableId:col1' because the UIComponent cannot be found
   Jun 11, 2018 3:13:29 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy saveDynamicActions
   WARNING: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:treeTableId:ol1' because the UIComponent cannot be found

A reference URL : [JSF State saving and custom components with dynamically added children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857584/jsf-state-saving-and-custom-components-with-dynamically-added-children)

The issue does not occur on MyFaces implementation. https://github.com/ravihariharan/primefaces-test-myfaces.git

I am not sure if this is a Mojarra partial state saving issue or a bug due to PrimeFaces.

BasicView1.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.data.treetable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.column.Column;
import org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel;
import org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTable;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Document;
import org.primefaces.showcase.service.DocumentService;

@ManagedBean(name = "ttBasicView1")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView1 implements Serializable {

    private String testString = "";

    private TreeNode root;

    private Document selectedDocument;

    @ManagedProperty("#{documentService}")
    private DocumentService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = service.createDocuments();

        TreeTable table = new TreeTable();
        table.setId("treeTableId");
        table.setVar("document");
        table.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{ttBasicView1.root}", TreeNode.class));

        Column column = new Column();
        column.setId("col1");
        OutputLabel label = new OutputLabel();
        label.setId("ol1");
        label.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{document.name}", String.class));

        column.getChildren().add(label);

        table.getChildren().add(column);

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
        viewRoot.findComponent("form:mainPanel").getChildren().add(table);
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setService(DocumentService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Document getSelectedDocument() {
        return selectedDocument;
    }

    public void setSelectedDocument(Document selectedDocument) {
        this.selectedDocument = selectedDocument;
    }

    public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(facesContext.getELContext(),
                valueExpression, valueType);
    }

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }



}
```

Document.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Document implements Serializable, Comparable<Document> {

    private String name;

    private String size;

    private String type;

    public Document(String name, String size, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    //Eclipse Generated hashCode and equals
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((size == null) ? 0 : size.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Document other = (Document) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (size == null) {
            if (other.size != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!size.equals(other.size))
            return false;
        if (type == null) {
            if (other.type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Document document) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(document.getName());
    }
}
```

treetableprogram.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>#{ttBasicView1.testString}</h1>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:panel id="mainPanel" header="">
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Raised also in forum.primeface https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=55937

Comment: Can you make a real small [mcve]? that can be posted inline here. Use all sorts of defaults, static array etc... I'm curious and since I'm going to need this as well (including upgrading to 6.2) I want to investigate. But there is too much code in your git project for me

Comment: https://github.com/ravihariharan/primefaces-test-treetable.git